# Does adding schema.org questions schema enhance SEO of my page?

Tags: seo, schema.org, rich-snippets, google-ranking

I have user generated questions and answers on my site.

1. Should we add https://schema.org/Question schema on this ?
2. What would be the SEO implications of adding this schema ?

Any example site that is using this schema and getting benefit would be of great help.

Comment: There are so many schema tags, and Google don't using them all. Question schema tags I have not seen in developer.google.com for markup body content. John Muller already said we don't use schema tags in ranking right now.

Comment: @Goyllo is right. However, I always recommend using schema.org mark-up where you can anyway for the simple reason that it can help in other areas such as the knowledge graph, featured snippet, etc. If not today, then perhaps tomorrow or later. It allows Google to understand your content better and that sometimes shows up in amazing ways. Sometimes not. But you will never know without the mark-up. And you never know what plans any search engine has that can suddenly show up. Cheers!!

Comment: I recommend never using any machine readable markup in your page unless you get some benefit from it.  Using makes your site easier to scrape.  It is easier to steal your data with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is no... however additional information appearing in the serps can indirectly improve your SEO because people are more inclined to click things that shows additional information, particularly review stars as a good example.

Obviously the more traffic your site receives the higher the chance of someone linking to the site or sharing it on social media which effectively increases your SEO directly, and naturally.

> [SOURCE](https://moz.com/learn/seo/schema-structured-data)
>
> Whether structured data affects rankings has been the subject of much
>   discussion and many experiments. As of yet, there is no conclusive
>   evidence that this markup improves rankings. But there are some
>   indications that search results with more extensive rich snippets
>   (like those created using Schema) will have a better click-through
>   rate. For best results, experiment with Schema markup to see how your
>   audience responds to the resulting rich snippets.